# How to combine/merge more than one queryset in to single queryset django

Tags: python, django, merge, django-queryset

I have a `queryset` as below

```
entries = [<Entry: Entry got issues>, <Entry: Entry Latest entry>, <Entry: Entry now tested>]
```

Each `object` in the above queryset `entries` will have a queryset as below

```
for entry in entries:
    print entry.tags.all()
```

**Result**

```
[<Tag: published>, <Tag: tags>, <Tag: needs>, <Tag: be>, <Tag: issues>, <Tag: to>]
[<Tag: abcd>]
[<Tag: abcd>, <Tag: nothing>]
```

so i want to merge the above three querysets in the result on to a single queryset as below

```
[<Tag: published>, <Tag: tags>, <Tag: needs>, <Tag: be>, <Tag: issues>, <Tag: to>]
 <Tag: abcd>, <Tag: abcd>, <Tag: nothing> ]
```

So how to `merge/combine` three querysets in to one above in django ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `|` operator.  i.e `queryset = queryset1 | queryset2 | queryset3` 
But you can also use the `&` operator to find intersection. You have to make sure that all the querysets return are of the same objects i.e Tag.

What you want to do basically is

```
queryset = entries[0].tags.all()
for entry in entries[1:]:
    queryset = queryset | entry.tags.all()
```

Comment: K but i am getting the querysets from the for loop as above, so how to merge them using `|` or `&` from for loop ?